# Изменение ширины ScrollBar при наведении на него

Tags: wpf, xaml, frontend

Есть вертикальный скролл, который при получении фокуса должен немного расширяться.

```
 <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}" >
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumbStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="True"/>

                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                        <Rectangle Fill="#36B448" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">               
            <Grid Background="#FFB1B1B1" Width="5" >

                <Track Name="PART_Track" IsDirectionReversed="True">
                    <Track.Thumb>
                        <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumbStyle}" />
                    </Track.Thumb>
                </Track>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
<Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollBar}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="22" />
            </Trigger>

            <!--<Trigger Property="Control.IsFocused" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="15"></Setter>
            </Trigger>-->
</Style.Triggers>
```

Незакомментированный триггер прекрасно работает, но триггер срабатывает не один раз при наведении курсора, второй (закомментированный) чисто теоретически должен работать, но этого не происходит.

Идеально было бы если `IsFocused` принимал значение `true` при наведении не только на сам скролл, но и область вокруг него (в размере 1-2 пикселей).Как это сделать?

У меня есть подозрение, что через `EventTrigger-ы` это реализовать проще.

Comment: А он вообще у вас может принимать фокус? (То есть, чему равно `Focusable`?)

Comment: При наведении курсора на область фокус сам по себе не возникает.

Comment: @VladD Focusable == True